# To check a number is a full prime number or not?

Tags: c, numbers, primes

I've got a problem with a time limit.

A full prime number is one for which the digits are all prime, the sum of the digits is prime, and the number is also prime.
Time limit per test is 1 sec. with t<=10^5 and 1 ≤ n ≤ 2.10^9.

It exceeded at test 54 :v.
What's wrong with my solution?

Also, the requirements don't allow me to use an array. Its purpose is just to use the loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

bool checkPrime(long long n) {
    
    if (n==2 || n==3)   return 1;
    if (n < 2 || n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0)
        return 0;
    for (long long i = 5; i <= n/i; i += 6) {
        if (n%i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    for (long long i = 7; i <= n/i; i += 6) {
        if (n%i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

bool checkDigits(long long n){ 
    while (n)
    {
        int i=n%10;
        
        if (i!=2 && i!=3 && i!=5 &&i !=7)   return 0;
        n/=10;
    }
    return 1;
}

int Sum(long long n){
    int sum=0;
    while (n){
        int i=n%10;
        sum+=i;
        n/=10;
    }
    return sum;
}

bool checkSum(long long n)
{
    long long m=Sum(n);
    return (checkPrime(m));
}

bool isFullPrime(long long n){
    if (checkDigits(n)==0)  return 0;
    if (checkSum(n)==0)   return 0;
    if (checkPrime(n)==0)   return 0;
    else    return 1;
}

int main(){
    
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--)
    {
        long long n;
        scanf("%lld", &n);
        
        if (isFullPrime(n))
        {
            printf("Yes\n");
        }
        else
            printf("No\n");                        
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should be a relatively small number of... numbers. Even in that range. I recommend using a Sieve of Eratosthenes technique along with the other checks to make an authoritative set of numbers in the range 1 to  2*10^9 that match the criteria. Then each check is a log n check in your authoritative set. Should reduce your current O(t * n) ~ O(t * 2billion) complexity down to O(t * log n) ~ O(t * 30).

Comment: It looks a bit as if you've not fully converted your working function names into English.  Please update the code so it is clearer what's what.  I think that `TongChuSo()` is also known as `Sum` and is written recursively.  You can probably avoid the recursion with iteration.

Comment: There are 9,592 primes smaller than 100,000; all composite numbers less than 2E9 have prime factors smaller than 100,000.  Even if you calculate a Sieve of Eratosthenes at run-time, using it will be much faster than recomputing whether a number is prime from first principles.  Also, the online definitions of 'full prime' only suggest that the number is prime and each of its digits is prime — no mention of 'sum of digits is prime' too.

Comment: Well i'm have just changed the language recently when i post it, may be i fogot that one. btw thanks for your comment

Comment: One of the tricks is that the test values `n` are certainly not random in the range _1 ≤ n ≤ 2.10^9_.  Instead I'd expect most of  the `n` are _Full prime_ with the worst case computations thrown in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use `unsigned`**

Given *1 ≤ n ≤ 2.10^9*, there is no need for the wide `long long`. Use `unsigned`, `int` or pedantically `uint_fast32_t` from `<stdint.h>`.

Potential speed-up: 4x

**Simplify prime detection**

Avoid checks like `n == 2` until needed.

Check small divisors first rather than `i = 5; i <= n/i; i += 6` then     `i = 7; i <= n/i; i += 6`.

```
bool checkPrime(unsigned n) {
  if (n % 2 == 0) {  // or n&1 == 0 if weak compiler.
    return n == 2;
  }
  if (n % 3 == 0) {
    return n == 3;
  }
  for (unsigned i = 5; i <= n / i; i += 4) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    i += 2;
    if (i > n / i) break;
    if (n % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return n > 1;
}
```

I expect the nearby `i <= n / i` and `n % i` to compile into  efficient code and effectively compute both for the price of one.

Could experiment and profile with `i*i <= n` versus `i <= n / i` (given range limitation) and using `int` with `div()`.  Such micro-optimizations might be worth it.  Usually not though.

Potential speed-up: 2x

**Sneaky: string literal**

Post has "requirements don't allow me to use an array" but apparently allows *string literals* like `"Yes\n"` and `"%d"` (which are technically arrays).

If *string literals* allowed, we can do a table look up for small tests.

```
bool checkDigits(unsigned n){ 
  while (n) {
    // if (i!=2 && i!=3 && i!=5 &&i !=7)   return 0;

    if ("\1\1\0\0\1\0\1\0\1\1"[n%10u]) return false;
    n/=10;
  }
  return true;
}
```

May a little speed-up - more of a [parlor trick](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/party_trick#English).

Comment: Dat Tran Xuan, did you meet time requirements?  What helped most?

Comment: Well it failed with case "2357", which your `checkPrime` got a problem. I'm still finding it. @
chux - Reinstate Monica

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it's accepted. I did know that my problem comes from the loop, but the way to fix it was not easy to me, well i got so many thing i have to learn.

Answer (score 1):

> [Wrong]For prime detection, you can take a better approach and try the `Sieve of Eratosthenes`.

I'm sorry that I don't see a limit to not using arrays, and I'll handle the problem in a different way.

`CheckDigits()` can be combined with `Sum()` when checking the number in each step, giving the Sum at the end.

```
int checkDigits(long long n){
    int sum=0;
    while (n)
    {
        int i=n%10;
        
        if (i!=2 && i!=3 && i!=5 &&i !=7)   return 0;
        sum += n%10;
        n/=10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Since `n < 2*10^9`, and `n` is `a full prime`, **each of its digits is prime**, its largest composition is 777777777.

The sum of the bits of any other values of `full prime` will be less than 7+7+7+7+7+7+7+7+7+7+7=63.

Primes within 63 include 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61. So, only these values can be detected when and is prime.

```
bool checkSum(long long n) {
    
    if (n==2 || n==3 || n==5 || n==7 || n==11 || n==13 || n==17 || n==19 || n==23 || n==29 || n==31 || n==37 || n==41 || n==43 || n==47 || n==53 || n==59 || n==61)   return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Answer] pages.  You should expand this with a link to an explanation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes or give an outline explanation of what it is — or both.  One possible reference is Wikipedia on [Primality
test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) — though that mostly skips poor old Eratosthenes — you need [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for that discussion.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will learn how to answer the questions and improve my previous suggestions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok, so maybe it's too much of a leap to say that the maximum sum of all prime bits is less than 63, I'll add a few more steps.

Comment: Consider helping your new `checkSum(n)` to quickly reject most evens.  `if (n % 2) return n == 2; if (n==3 || n==5 || ....`  Also consider `checkSum(long long n)` to `checkSum(int n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve `checkPrime` to perform 1/3 of the number of iterations:

```
bool checkPrime(long long n) {
    // handle special cases 0 thru 3
    if (n <= 3)
        return n >= 2;

    // eliminate multiples of 2 or 3
    if (n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0)
        return 0;

    for (long long i = 5; i*i <= n; i += 6) {
        if (n%i == 0)
            return 0;
    }

    for (long long i = 7; i*i <= n; i += 6) {
        if (n%i == 0)
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It is usually better to look for smaller numbers first — so you should combine the two loops so you can check 5 and 7, then 11 and 13, then 17 and 19, and so on, rather than checking 5, 11, 17, … and then 7, 13, 19, …. Also, checking `i <= n / i` is less susceptible to overflow than `i * i <= n`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: yeah, that's correct, I'll add an initial check of these two cases.